# why split does not work in yield comprehension scala

Tags: scala

i have this code:

```
case class DataText(name:String)
  val dataModels = Seq(DataText("a.dm"),DataText("b.dm"),DataText("c.dm"),DataText("d.dm"),DataText("e.dm"),DataText("f.dm"))
  val dataReports = Seq(DataText("a.dm"),DataText("b1.do"),DataText("c2.do"),DataText("d.do"),DataText("e3.do"),DataText("f5.do"))
```

why when i split the name in the yield i have this  result **res0**:

```
val dataRes = for {
    model <- dataModels
    report <- dataReports
  }yield {
    model.name.split(".").toList
  }

   res0:  List(List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List(), List())
```

but when i have this code i have this **res0**:

```
val dataRes = for {
    model <- dataModels
    report <- dataReports
  }yield {
    model.name
  }

  println(dataRes)

res0: List(a.dm, a.dm, a.dm, a.dm, a.dm, a.dm, b.dm, b.dm, b.dm, b.dm, b.dm, b.dm, c.dm, c.dm, c.dm, c.dm, c.dm, c.dm, d.dm, d.dm, d.dm, d.dm, d.dm, d.dm, e.dm, e.dm, e.dm, e.dm, e.dm, e.dm, f.dm, f.dm, f.dm, f.dm, f.dm, f.dm)
```

what is the reason that the split doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala's String is an alias for Java's String, and the method you're using to split the string is this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

The pitfall that got you is that the argument is a regex. So `"."` matches any single character. There are further pitfalls around the empty string and trailing delimiters that you might still fall in. It's quite a tricky API.

You can avoid this particular issue (but not the others) by using `split('.')`  which matches on the literal `.` character, or escaping it with `split("\\.")`

Answer (score 3):

According to the [document](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/StringOps.html#split(separator:Char):Array%5BString%5D)

> implemented in terms of String.split(re: String)

Thus, `"."` is treated as regular expression, which matches to any character.

You should try

```
.split('.')
```

instead.